# How to change position of button in android?

Tags: android, xml, button

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/robo">

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Max Time(Sec)">
</TextView>

<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="100"
 android:id="@+id/maximum" 
android:inputType="number">
</EditText>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Start" 
android:id="@+id/startbtn" 
android:focusable="true">
</Button>

<ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/icon" 
android:id="@+id/imageButton1">
</ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LinearLayout you can't change positions a whole lot - because the layout is Linear (sequential). But you can use layout_margin to somewhat move the widgets.

I don't know what you want to do, but you should look into FrameLayout (which will let you put the image anywhere!). My personal favorite is RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Position depends on position of it's parent container/component (Layout) and on it's layout_* properties.
And u did'n tell what u want. If u want change it position - switch it with another view in Layout.

Comment: Above is my code..now give me idea how to change my imageButton1 in above code.thanks in advance..

Comment: Please tell what u want to do. U asked to change position, but didn't tell what ImageButton's position u want.

Answer (score 0):

put more buttons in layout and hide or show them according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

views in android are in relationship, not only in RelativeLayout but in Others, so you should choose the best way to describe your app layout, using more than one is commonly used.
to change position of label, you 'd better using AbsoluteLayout then using android:layout_x="", android:layout_y=""

Answer (score 0):

what is your exact requirement???
you can put two buttons and make one visible and other one invisible or vice verse.or you can put layout_margin for all direction.And try to put all your component in different layout.